# How to send flash data in codeigniter when part of it is a link

Tags: codeigniter, flash, hyperlink

I have to show flash data which contains a link. I tried the following but link is not shown as it should.

How can I add link in flashdata?
I tried this:

```
$cancell =  "<a href='<?php echo site_url('document/index');?>Cancell</a>"; 
             $this->session->set_flashdata('success',
                'You successfully created the document! ' . $cancell .', if you want to cancell it!');
    redirect('document/index/');
```

Comment: `redirect('document/index/');` when you use this it will reload page. So your flash data alws keep lost. use `$this->load->view();`

Comment: Flash data is shown. My problem is that link is shown in this way when you click on Cancell link : http://localhost:9080/projectname/index.php/Document/<?php echo site_url(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try some thing like this code below, but make sure **url helper autoloaded**

[URL Helper Codeigniter](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/helpers/url_helper.html)

**Controller**

```
$link = anchor('document/index', 'cancel');

$message = 'You successfully created the document!' .' '. $link .' '. 'if you want to cancell it!';

$this->session->set_flashdata('success', $message);

redirect('document/index');
```

**View**

`<p><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('success');?></p>`

Comment: You must autoload session from libraries too :)